# rltk vga font not displaying properly

Tags: rust

I'm building a simple game with rltk. 8x8 simple font works fine but when I try to change that to builtin 8x16 VGA font, it kind of stretches and shifts the fontface like this:

[image: Rust font fail]

I initialize the window like this:

```rust
fn main() -> rltk::BError {
    use rltk::RltkBuilder;
    let context = RltkBuilder::vga(42, 42)
        .build()?;
    let mut gs = State {
        ecs: World::new()
    };
    gs.ecs.insert(init_gamedata());
    rltk::main_loop(context, gs)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the fonts are well-formed? Also provide more information, such as what's inside `init_gamedata`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently Rltk ships with .png texture and you're supposed to use that and you have to specify it. Like this:

```
fn main() -> rltk::BError {
  use rltk::RltkBuilder;
  let context = RltkBuilder::vga(42, 42)
    .with_font("vga8x16.png", 8, 16)
    .build()?;
  let mut gs = State {
    ecs: World::new()
  };
  gs.ecs.insert(init_gamedata());
  rltk::main_loop(context, gs)
}
```